# AngularJS directive for updating IFrame's body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive

I would like to bind a model property to an iframe's body.

With jQuery, The logic would have to be written something like

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').html('<p>Hello</p>');
```

Ideally, i would like the AngularJS directive to be something like..

```
<myframe body="model.safehtml"></myframe>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the DOM in the `link` function of a Angular [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
app.directive('myframe', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        body: '='
    },
    template: "<iframe></iframe>",
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        elm.find('iframe').contents().find('body').html(scope.body);
    }
  };
});
```